# Cordova inappbrowser status bar iOS 7

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm using Cordova with an InAppBrowser to show an external webpage (jquery-mobile site). In the cordova app, I use the Statusbar plugin. Everything looks nice and dandy when the inappbrowser is opened. But, as soon as you start scrolling in page, the webpage content shows up behind the status bar.

[image]

This is a known bug CB-4930 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4930) in the inappbrowser but I can't find a workaround.
The bug was reopened after a correction was made. Prior the correction, it was possible to add a white div at the top but this is not possible anymore.

Please need help, this one is killing me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After great support from Shazron Abdullah at the Cordova project team the bug is solved. 
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4930 for more details.

So, just pick the lastest version of InAppBrowser.